# How to remove all duplicate value when fetch data from Database in Django view page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 tables in my database `product` and `skuoption`, the `skuoption` table has `variant_id` and this `variant_id` is storing multiple times with the same fields in `skuoption` table, please let me know how I can remove the duplicate value of `variant_id` when I fetch data on view page.

here is my code for `product-view.html` file...

```
  <h3>₹ {{product.saleprice}}</h3>
                       <div class="product-description border-product">
                            <div class="size-box">
                                <ul><b>Select Size: </b>
                                    {% for sku in product.skuoption_set.all %}
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void()">{{sku.variantsize}}</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div></div>
```

what condition i can add here (`{% for sku in product.skuoption_set.all %}`) or here `{{sku.variantsize}}`) so that i can remove duplicate values from my view page.
Please have a look in the screenshot, which duplicate value i want to remove.
[image]

Here is my `models.py file...

```
class Size(models.Model):
    variant=models.ForeignKey('Variants', related_name='var_size', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=285)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

this is for `skuoption` table

```
class SkuOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variantflavour=models.ForeignKey('Flavour', related_name='varflavour', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    variantsize=models.ForeignKey('Size', related_name='varsize', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sku=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    qty=models.CharField(max_length=285, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku
```

Comment: Try using [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct): `for sku in product.skuoption_set.distinct.all`

Comment: it's not working, do u have any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query in your view function

```
variantsizes = product.skuoption_set.values('variantsize__name').distinct()
variantsizes_list = [rec['variantsize__name'] for rec in variantsizes]
context = {'variantsizes_list':variantsizes_list}
```

**template**

```
<div class="product-description border-product">
    <div class="size-box">
        <ul><b>Select Size: </b>
            {% for size in variantsizes_list %}
            <li><a href="javascript:void()">{{size}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working perfect, but it's giving me the `variantsize_id` in numeric format, how I can get the actual name of `variantsize_id`, because `variantsize_id=1` is coming from `variantsize` table.

Comment: I didn't get you. Please provide your output and model stucture

Comment: Please check this screenshot after opening this URL...`https://prnt.sc/tlxp1z`

Comment: what field did you provide in values?

Comment: Please check my both table in these screenshot `https://prnt.sc/tlxrcy` and with relationship `https://prnt.sc/tlxqd7`

Comment: I want to display `small` and `medium` instead of `[1,2]` on view page

Comment: then you can go for  `variantsizes = product.skuoption_set.values('variantsize__name').distinct()`

Comment: Got your answer?

Comment: giving me keyerror in this line `variantsizes_list = [rec['variantsize'] for rec in variantsizes]`, i am using your code which you privided.

Comment: Please Check Now

Comment: it's working perfect, but coming in list format `https://prnt.sc/tly2i7`, and I updated my model also.

Comment: yes now in the template instead of using `for sku in product.skuoption_set.distinct.all` use `for size in variantsizes_list`

Comment: please verify and upvote if you appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218290/discussion-between-saini-tor-and-pruthvi-barot).